# SP13: Filtering Default Calendar Start and End Time

Tags: 2013, list, calendar, filter

I am working off of a list from a calendar.  Within the calendar list I am to filter all event columns except Start Time and End Time field.  See image below for a visual example.

Does anyone know why I cannot filter start time and end time on a calendar list, but can filter on a regular custom list or document library?

Thanks for your help!

[image: Column with Filter]

[image: Column without Filter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design and I am not sure why they made it like that.

There's a nice workaround with calculated columns that can query this column

http://gunnarpeipman.com/2007/10/filtering-sharepoint-calendar-by-start-time/